# iOS - Firebase Authorization/login with email

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have seen so much questions about authorization in Firebase, but none of them helped (*the authorization way was a bit different*). I am not so experienced iOS development so I need help not only in the code, but in UX also. Below is is my code:

```
func loginDidFinish(email: String, password: String, type: LFLoginController.SendType) {

    // Server call implementation here
    if type == .Login {
        if user.exists { // check if user exists
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email, password: password, completion: {
                navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
            })
        } else {
            self.controller.wrongInfoShake()
        }
    } else { // type == .SignUp
        if user.exists { // check if user exists
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
                //
            })
        } else {
            FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
                //
            })
        }
    }

    print(email)
    print(password)
    print(type)

    // handling errors
    if email == "" && password == "" {
        controller.wrongInfoShake()
    } else {
        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

This is my function for logging-in. First, I used a framework for login page (*yes, I am too lazy to do that myself*) from [here](https://github.com/awesome-labs/LFLoginController). And I used Firebase as a backend server to store that accounts.

Now, I don't know how to check if the user already exists in the system. Also, if there any errors occurs the `LFLoginController` lib provides with function called `wrongInfoShake()`, which I use every time when an error occurs, but I'm not sure if I should provide the description that went wrong (*means to present `AlertControl`*) (*this is UX question btw*).

And when the type is changed to *SignUp*, will it be OK when the user types the email and password that already exists to login using that info even if the user uses type SignUp?

When the SignUp goes on, should I handle any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bit of questions here and I'll try to answer all of them:

1. The best way to check if a user already exists, is in the `completionBlock` of `signInWithEmail()` and `createUserWithEmail()`, if an error happened you know this could be one of the cases. If you still want to have a method for this, there is a new call to the API called `fetchProvidersForEmail()` that returns an array of providers, in your case the e-mail one.
2. Don't use an alert controller for that, that would be overuse, just show an error label stating the `Login was incorrect`, or `An error occured`, or whatever error you want to show. Try to avoid alerts unless really needed.
3. The user is already used to getting the error of `User already exists` when trying to sign up with his e-mail, and from the UX perspective it would induce some errors as he would think of it as of a clear, new account, so no, just show a label stating that the user exists, it's very unprobabilistic that someone else has registered with his e-mail.
4. When signing up, firebase can give the error that the `E-mail already exists`, like I mentioned in point 3, and if the e-mail handling was wrong, it can also give the `Invalid e-mail`. This and all other errors should be handled by showing some message to the user or he will get confused. To handle them, just check the error in the `completion`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the [Firebase UI Auth](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/FirebaseUI/Auth):

"FirebaseUI provides a drop-in auth solution that handles the UI flows for signing in users with email addresses and passwords, Google Sign-In, and Facebook Login. It is built on top of Firebase Auth.

The FirebaseUI Auth component implement best practices for authentication on mobile devices and websites, which can maximize sign-in and sign-up conversion for your app. It also handles edge cases like account recovery and account linking that can be security sensitive and error-prone to handle correctly.

FirebaseUI can be easily customized to fit in with the rest of your app's visual style, and it is open source, so you aren't constrained in realizing the user experience you want."